# give parameter(list or array) to in operator - python, sql

Tags: python, sql, parameters, in-clause

I have a list in python.

```
article_ids = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

I need to use this list in sql statement like this :

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE article_id IN (article_ids)
```

How can I provide this list to my `IN()` clause?

I have already try some ways which I googled, but I couldn't figure it out.

```
>> print ids_list
    placeholders= ', '.join('?'*len(ids_list))  # "?, ?, ?, ... ?"
    query = 'SELECT article_id FROM article_author_institution WHERE institution_id IN ({})'.format(placeholders)
    print query
    cursor.execute(query, ids_list)
```

Error message I get:

```
SELECT article_id FROM article_author_institution WHERE institution_id IN (?)
     query = query % db.literal(args)
    TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

For example for:

```
ids_list = [9,10]

placeholders= ', '.join('%'*len(ids_list))  # "?, ?, ?, ... ?"
query = 'SELECT aid FROM article_author_institution WHERE instid IN ({})'.format(placeholders)
print query
cursor.execute(query, ids_list)
```

The output and error message are:

```
SELECT aid FROM article_author_institution WHERE instid IN (%, %)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "deneme3.py", line 11, in <module>
    cursor.execute(query, ids_list)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 159, in execute
    query = query % db.literal(args)
ValueError: unsupported format character ',' (0x2c) at index 61
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The idea is to have a query like this one:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT ... IN (%s, %s, %s)", (1, 2, 3))
```

where each `%s` will be substituted by elements in your list. To construct this string query you can do:

```
placeholders= ', '.join(['%s']*len(article_ids))  # "%s, %s, %s, ... %s"
query = 'SELECT name FROM table WHERE article_id IN ({})'.format(placeholders)
```

finally

```
cursor.execute(query, tuple(article_ids))
```

Comment: Not work again, i editted and put the output and my code to the question. If you check and help, i will appreciated

Comment: Are you using sqlite? What DB are you using? What python driver?

Comment: Db is mysql , python version is 2.7

Comment: Which module are you using to access the DB from python?

Comment: Thats the problem, I assumed Sqlite, in MySQL we need `%s` instead of `?`. Please try my updated answer.

Comment: You made a small mistake copying the code, in `placeholders=` line, replace `'%'` with `['%s']`, or copy paste directly from answer.

Comment: thank you to the question poster and this answer!

Answer (score 8):

I think the right option is to use tuples data structure. Hope below code helps you.

```
article_ids = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
ids = tuple(article_ids)
query = "SELECT name FROM table WHERE article_id IN {}".format(ids)
cursor.execute(query)
```

Comment: I honestly feel like this is the best, cleanest answer.  Not sure why I'm the only upvote ...  

Comment: cleanest answer! thank you

Comment: Thank you, Andrew Einhorn & Hanan Atallah

Comment: This solution is prone to sql injection attacks. The accepted answer is the safest way to do it.

Comment: Jp Reddy thanks for this clarification!

Comment: You will get a syntax error if the list has only 1 item, this is because Python will convert the tuple like this (1,) ... so the comma will cause a syntax error in the database statement

Comment: @AndrewEinhorn that's a SQL injection bug, not a clean answer.

Answer (score 2):

For Python3 you can use

```
article_ids = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
sql_list = str(tuple([key for key in article_ids])).replace(',)', ')')
query ="""
    SELECT id FROM table WHERE article_id IN {sql_list}
""".format(sql_list=sql_list)
```

resulting in

```
>>> print(query)

    SELECT id FROM table WHERE article_id IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
```

which you can feed to

```
cursor.execute(query)
```

This also works for article_ids of only 1 value (where tuple generates `(1,)`).

It also works for arrays of strings:

```
article_titles = ['some', 'article titles']
```

resulting in

```
    SELECT id FROM table WHERE article_title IN ('some', 'article titles')
```

Comment: `str(tuple([key for key in article_ids])).replace(',)', ')')` saved me a lot of time. thanks!

Comment: This method is also prone to SQL injection attacks

Comment: Can you explain the .format(sqllist=sqllist) at the end of the query please?

Comment: .format(sql_list=sql_list) means replace the string {sql_list} in the query in line 4 with the value of sql_list as set in line 2.